# ReactJS redirect on page switch with Keycloak authentication

Tags: reactjs, react-router, keycloak, keycloak-nodejs-connect

I have created a ReactJS UI that uses Keycloak to authenticate users.

I used this tutorial with some minor tweaks: https://blog.logrocket.com/implement-keycloak-authentication-react/

I am using:

- React Router
- keycloak-js
- @react-keycloak/web

Now the problem is that when I am routing between the different pages of my application it redirect through a page with variables in the URL.

I added a screenshot of the redirect url. After the redirect shown in the image I get redirected again to the correct page (in this case /secured).

[image: After click on the link to the "secured" page]

This behaviour is not really what I expected from a SPA.

I want it to redirect to the page I click without any step inbetween.

If you need anything else I am happy to provide information/code snippets.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

The tutorial I used used `<a href="/">` to route between components.

After switching it to `<Link>` from react-router-dom it works like expected.